# The ppp0 interface uses the eth0 interface

Tags: ubuntu, networking, interface

I am trying to set up a ppp interface on an ubuntu-server 16.10 where there is already a enp1s0 interface. When I deleted the default route linked to the interface enp1s0, I could use the ppp0 interface but I want to use both interfaces simultaneously.

To achieve that I added a route table named ppp in /etc/iproute2/interface. Then I created a routing policy for the table ppp as follows:

```
ip route add 100.78.26.0/24 dev ppp0 src 100.78.26.117 table ppp
ip route add default via 100.78.26.117 dev ppp0 table ppp
ip rule add from 100.78.26.117/32 table ppp
ip rule add to 100.78.26.117/32 table ppp
```

The routes are set up. The problem is that the interface ppp0 is up but passes through the interface enp1s0 to connect to the internet.

There is the result of route -n :

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp1s0
10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp1s0
```

This is the result of ip route show table all :

```
default via 100.78.26.117 dev ppp0  table ppp 
100.78.26.0/24 dev ppp0  table ppp  scope link  src 100.78.26.117 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp1s0 
10.64.64.64 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src 100.78.26.117 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.39 
local 100.78.26.117 dev ppp0  table local  proto kernel  scope host  src 100.78.26.117
```

I need some help to make those two interfaces work simultaneously.

Ps : this is the ppp configuration script :

```
nodetach
nolock
/dev/ttyUSB7
115200
local
asyncmap 0
user ""
password ""
crtscts
modem
hide-password
usepeerdns
noauth
noipdefault
novj
novjccomp
noccp
debug
defaultroute
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
connect 'chat -s -v -f /etc/ppp/peers/free-chat-connect'
```

Comment: If this is a system administration question rather than a programming question, it might fit better on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in doing this once. My observations might help you, they are recorded here: https://gist.github.com/vyuh/98b38b29928e67e0ae3dd000a9d0f7b3.

http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html is the original page that had helped me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still doesn't work. As a matter of fact it is the ping via the ppp interface that uses the enp1s0 interface whereas the curl command succeeds in using both interfaces and this was already the case with my old configuration.